# Django throws error when having multiple forms in formsets while making POST request

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django project with a dashboard and forms with formsets built in django admin. I'm trying to make a POST request from the forms to an API. I have two formsets to be specific. When I have more than one form in either of the formsets i am getting the below error. A single form however is going through. Below is my code and the error,

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/campaign/add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 45, in _wrapped_view_func
    add_never_cache_headers(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 252, in add_never_cache_headers
    patch_response_headers(response, cache_timeout=-1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 243, in patch_response_headers
    if not response.has_header('Expires'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

forms.py

```
class CampaignForm(forms.Form):
    consumer = forms.CharField(label="Consumer", max_length=200)
    startDate = forms.DateTimeField(label="Start Date",
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'])
    endDate = forms.DateTimeField(label="End Date",
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'])
    referreeCredits = forms.IntegerField(label="Referree Credits")
    referrerCredits = forms.IntegerField(label="Referrer Credits")
    maxReferreeCredits = forms.IntegerField(label="Max Referree Credits")
    maxReferrerCredits = forms.IntegerField(label="Max Referrer Credits")
    message = forms.CharField(label="Message", max_length=200)
    kramerTemplateId = forms.CharField(label="Kramer Template ID", max_length=200)
    paymentMode = forms.ChoiceField(label="Payment Mode", choices=[("PAYTM","PAYTM")])

class RuleForm(forms.Form):
    eventName = forms.CharField(label="Event Name", max_length=200)
    operator = forms.ChoiceField(label="Operator", choices=[("EQUAL","EQUAL"), ("EVERY","EVERY")])
    value = forms.IntegerField(label="Value")

class MilestoneRulesForm(forms.Form):
    operator = forms.ChoiceField(label="Operator", choices=[("EQUAL","EQUAL"), ("EVERY","EVERY")])
    value = forms.IntegerField(label="Value")
    referrerCredits = forms.IntegerField(label="Referrer Credits")
```

views.py

```
def campaign_add(self, request):
        form = CampaignForm()
        RuleFormSet = formset_factory(RuleForm)
        MilestoneFormSet = formset_factory(MilestoneRulesForm)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
            form = CampaignForm(request.POST)
            rule_formset = RuleFormSet(request.POST, prefix='rules')
            milestone_formset = MilestoneFormSet(request.POST, prefix='milestones')
            if form.is_valid() and rule_formset.is_valid() and milestone_formset.is_valid():
                    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
                    dat = {}
                    dat["consumer"] = form.cleaned_data["consumer"]
                    dat["startDate"] = self.datetime_to_epoch(form.cleaned_data["startDate"])
                    dat["endDate"] = self.datetime_to_epoch(form.cleaned_data["endDate"])
                    dat["referreeCredits"] = form.cleaned_data["referreeCredits"]
                    dat["referrerCredits"] = form.cleaned_data["referrerCredits"]
                    dat["maxReferreeCredits"] = form.cleaned_data["maxReferreeCredits"]
                    dat["maxReferrerCredits"] = form.cleaned_data["maxReferrerCredits"]
                    dat["message"] = form.cleaned_data["message"]
                    dat["kramerTemplateId"] = form.cleaned_data["kramerTemplateId"]
                    dat["paymentMode"] = form.cleaned_data["paymentMode"]
                    arrRules = rule_formset.cleaned_data
                    arrMilestoneRules = milestone_formset.cleaned_data
                    dat["eventRules"] = arrRules
                    dat["milestoneRules"] = arrMilestoneRules
                    print(rule_formset.cleaned_data)
                    print(milestone_formset.cleaned_data)
                    res = requests.post("https://example.com", data=json.dumps(dat), headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
                    if res.status_code == 201 or res.status_code == 200:
                        messages.success(request, 'Success!')
                        return redirect("admin:campaign-pg1")
                    else:
                        messages.error(request, 'Submission Failed.')
        else:
            rule_formset = RuleFormSet(prefix="rules")
            milestone_formset = MilestoneFormSet(prefix="milestones")
            return TemplateResponse(request, "admin/campaign_add.html", {"form":form, "rule_formset": rule_formset, "milestone_formset": milestone_formset})
```

Html template:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="form_div" style="width:60%;">
        <h2>Campaign Form</h2>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ field.label_tag }}
                    {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
                    {% if field.help_text %}
                        <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}            
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; width: 280px;">
                <h3>Rules</h3>
                <button type="button" id="generate-rule" class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="parent">
            <div>
            {{ rule_formset.management_form }}
            {% for ruleForm in rule_formset %}
                {{ ruleForm }}
                <input type="button"  class="btn btn-warn" style="background: red;" value="-">
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
            </div>
             <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; width: 280px;">
                <h3>Milestone Rules</h3>
                <button  type="button" id="generate-milestone-rule" class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="milestone-parent">
            <div>
            {{ milestone_formset.management_form }}
            {% for milestoneForm in milestone_formset %}
                {{ milestoneForm }}
                <input type="button"  class="btn btn-warn" style="background: red;" value="-">
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Post">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#id_startDate").datetimepicker({
            format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
            });
            $("#id_endDate").datetimepicker({
            format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        const ruleform = `
        <div>
            <label for="id_rules-{n}-eventName">Event Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="rules-{n}-eventName" maxlength="200" id="id_rules-{n}-eventName">

            <label for="id_rules-{n}-operator">Operator:</label>
            <select name="rules-{n}-operator" id="id_rules-{n}-operator">
                <option value="EQUAL">EQUAL</option>
                <option value="EVERY">EVERY</option>
            </select>

            <label for="id_rules-{n}-value">Value:</label>
            <input type="number" name="rules-{n}-value" id="id_rules-{n}-value">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-warn" style="background: red;" value="-">
        </div>
        `
        const milestoneform = `
        <div>
            <label for="id_milestones-{n}-operator">Operator:</label>
            <select name="milestones-{n}-operator" id="id_milestones-{n}-operator">
                <option value="EQUAL">EQUAL</option>
                <option value="EVERY">EVERY</option>
            </select>

            <label for="id_milestones-{n}-value">Value:</label>
            <input type="number" name="milestones-{n}-value" id="id_milestones-{n}-value">

            <label for="id_milestones-{n}-mreferrerCredits">Referrer Credits:</label>
            <input type="number" name="milestones-{n}-mReferrerCredits" maxlength="200" id="id_milestones-{n}-mReferrerCredits">

            <input type="button" class="btn btn-warn" style="background: red;" value="-">
        </div>
        `
        $("#generate-rule").on('click', function(e){
            var n = $("#id_rules-TOTAL_FORMS").val(); // current number of forms;
            var new_form = ruleform.replace(/{n}/g, n); // replace all {n} by the new form number
            $(".parent").append(new_form);
            $("#id_rules-TOTAL_FORMS").val(parseInt(n) + 1); // update the total forms number
            console.log($("#id_rules-TOTAL_FORMS").val());
        })
        $("#generate-milestone-rule").on('click', function(e){
             var n = $("#id_milestones-TOTAL_FORMS").val(); // current number of forms;
            var new_form = milestoneform.replace(/{n}/g, n); // replace all {n} by the new form number
            $(".milestone-parent").append(new_form);
            $("#id_milestones-TOTAL_FORMS").val(parseInt(n) + 1); // update the total forms number
            console.log($("#id_milestones-TOTAL_FORMS").val());
        })
        $(".parent").on("click", (e) => {
            //n = $("#id_rules-TOTAL_FORMS").val();
            //$("#id_rules-TOTAL_FORMS").val(parseInt(n)-1);
            //console.log($("#id_rules-TOTAL_FORMS").val());
            return e.target.classList.contains('btn-warn') && e.target.parentNode.remove()
        })

        $(".milestone-parent").on("click", (e) => {
            //n = $("#id_milestones-TOTAL_FORMS").val();
            //$("#id_milestones-TOTAL_FORMS").val(parseInt(n)-1);
            //console.log($("#id_milestones-TOTAL_FORMS").val());
            return e.target.classList.contains('btn-warn') && e.target.parentNode.remove()
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

How do I solve this error so I can make a POST request with any number of forms in my formsets?

Edit:
This is what my formset looks like. When I have more than one form I am getting the above error.
[my formsets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hckWg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could it be that you are reaching a condtion the status code of your request is invalid (not 200 or 201)? When that is the case you are not returning any response you are just calling:

```
else:
    messages.error(request, 'Submission Failed.')
```

The stacktrace of your exception suggests that there is no response object (you are not returning any response from the view)

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 243, in patch_response_headers
    if not response.has_header('Expires'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

Check why the api call fails and solve the problem and then you should be able to submit your form.

Comment: Hi. But why am i getting an error when I have more than one form in rules and milestone rules whereas the request is going through when I have just one form in the same.

Comment: It seems like most of your form fields are required fields. It could be that if you have more than one form you are submitting empty forms which would not pass validation. The only way to find out is to look at all of your formsets['errors'] attribute (with pdb or with a print statement) and also at your form['errors'] attribute

Answer (score 0):

By default, formset_factory() defines one extra form. The number of empty forms that is displayed is controlled by the extra parameter.

```
MilestoneFormSet = formset_factory(MilestoneForm, extra=2)
RuleFormSet = formset_factory(RuleForm, extra=2)
```